# J2me web service connection problem

Tags: web-services, java-me, xml-rpc

i'm trying to connect to a php web service using kxml-rpc api and the code is as simple as this:

```
XmlRpcClient xmlrpc = new XmlRpcClient("http://***ip here***:88/secure/service");

Vector parameters = new Vector();
parameters.addElement("value");

String result = (String) (xmlrpc.execute("functionName", parameters));
```

Mobile device asks for permission to connect to GPS. But somehow the result is always null.

What can be done? and what configuration i should check?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the web service provider is actually invoked, and what does it return. It is not unlikely that it returns null, (so the clients gets it).

Comment: it is how you said. server send the result but client gets it as null.